# What's the difference between Wifi and Bluetooth?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

What is the difference between Wifi (802.11 "wireless") and Bluetooth?

Comment: That's like asking for the difference between a dolphin and a porpose.  Bluetooth is wireless (though wireless isn't necessarily Bluetooth).

Comment: Might help if you specified a particular use for wireless technology to give some context.

Comment: Because Our Super[user](s) making me to confuse ..

Comment: You're talking about WiFi and Bluetooth, right?

Comment: yes .. Thats correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has good articles on both [802.11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) WiFi technologies and [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) technologies.

[Wikipedias quick summary of the differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_vs._Wi-Fi_IEEE_802.11_in_networking):

> Bluetooth and Wi-Fi have many
>   applications in today's offices,
>   homes, and on the move: setting up
>   networks, printing, or transferring
>   presentations and files from PDAs to
>   computers. Both are versions of
>   unlicensed wireless technology. Wi-Fi
>   is intended for resident equipment and
>   its applications. The category of
>   applications is outlined as WLAN, the
>   wireless local area networks. Wi-Fi is
>   intended as a replacement for cabling
>   for general local area network access
>   in work areas. Bluetooth is intended
>   for non resident equipment and its
>   applications. The category of
>   applications is outlined as the
>   wireless personal area network (WPAN).
>   Bluetooth is a replacement for cabling
>   in a variety of personally carried
>   applications in any ambience.

So basicly, 802.11 is an addition to the networking and connecting of computers & smartphones supporting high-bandwidth, and covers large areas.

Bluetooth is a [ad-hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad-hoc) wireless technology which works at low distances, making it perfect for file tansfersing and remote-control hardware.

Answer (score 5):

Wireless is a general term talking about any type of communication that involves communication without wires.  [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) is a specific wireless technology.

Bluetooth is used for low bandwidth, short range wireless (usually only a few feet) communication typically between devices such as phones, computers, GPSs, etc.

Examples of other wireless technologies include:

- [802.11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11) (Wifi) - Used for traditional IP data, such as internet traffic, over short distances
- [WiMax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiMax) - Broadband like IP data.
- [GSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM) - Used in cell phones

Answer (score 0):

When most people talk about "wireless" they are probably talking about a particular wireless protocol called [IEEE802.11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) which is used for wireless networks. [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_vs._Wi-Fi_IEEE_802.11_in_networking) however is an alternative wireless protocol and is typically used for short range 1-1 communication and was originally designed as a wireless replacement for RS232 serial cables.